# Como executar um arquivo .bat a partir de um algoritmo em C?

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia executar um arquivo externo (um .bat, por exemplo) a partir de um algoritmo em C.

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples, se estiver no mesmo diretório é só chamar assim:

```
system("nome.bat");
```

ou você pode chamar com o caminho completo também, por ex:

```
system("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\teste.bat");
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui! Brigadão, cara!